# Visual Basic 6: Resource Editor shows no resources

Tags: vb6, resources, basic

I've inherited a VB6 project that uses resources, and they work fine, but when I open the resource file with the resource editor, there are no resources there! Googling hasn't turned up any similar problems.

Anyone have an idea how to get access to the project's resources? Thanks!

Comment: It turns out the geniuses who created this project made their own resource file with their own custom format! Arrgh...the joys of legacy code!

Comment: Just to be sure, When you say "the resource editor" you have tried the built-in ["VB6 Resource Editor add-in"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228672(v=vs.60).aspx)